# Capybara - Poltergeist - JavascriptError: Undefined is not a constructor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

I have this strange error in a new project where i want to work with Angular and make a ajax-search through fake data. The search is working, but when i try to create a test with the environment PhantomJS, Capybara, Rspec, Webpack and angular an error occurs. 
Versions:

- phantomjs: 2.1.1 (checked in console with `phantomjs -v`
- webpacker (3.0.2 3b09f78)
- websocket-driver (0.6.5)
- websocket-extensions (0.1.2)
- rspec-core (3.7.0)
- rspec-rails (3.7.1)
- capybara (2.15.4)

Here is my test spec/features/product_search_spec.rb :

```rb
require 'rails_helper'

feature 'product search' do
  let(:email) {"username@mail.dk"}
  let(:password) {"passwordpassword"}

  before do
    create_test_user(email, password)

    create_product("Christan", "Zebra", "Andersen")
    create_product("Mathias", "Aude", "Zebra")
    create_product("Zebaa", "Zulu", "Hest")
    create_product("Aaaaaaaaa", "Zebra", "Aaaaaaa") # Første produkt, der bliver vis

  end

  scenario "Search by title" do
    visit root_path
    fill_in "Email", with: email
    fill_in "Password", with: password
    click_button "Log in"

    click_link "Gå til produktsøgning"

    sleep 1
    puts page.body
    within ".search-form" do
      fill_in "keywords", with: "Zeb"
    end

    within "section.search-results" do
      expect(page).to have_content("Zebra")
      list_group_items = page.all("ol li.list-group-item")
      expect(list_group_items.count).to eq(4)
      expect(list_group_items[0]).to have_content("Zebaa") # Er det sorteret rigtigt?
    end

  end
end

def create_test_user email, password
  User.create!(
    email: email,
    password: password,
    password_confirmation: password
  )
end

# For at jeg og senere udvikler tydeligt kan se hvilken test-data, som det er vi arbejder med.
def create_product title, subtitle, authors
  title ||= Faker::Internet.username
  subtitle ||= Faker::Internet.domain_name
  authors ||= Faker::FamilyGuy.character

  Product.create!(
    title: title,
    subtitle: subtitle,
    authors: authors
  )
end
```

When i run `rails spec SPEC=spec/features/product_search_spec.rb`

I get an error in the terminal:

```
product search Search by title
     Failure/Error: click_link "Gå til produktsøgning"

     Capybara::Poltergeist::JavascriptError:
       One or more errors were raised in the Javascript code on the page. If you don't care about these errors, you can ignore them by setting js_errors: false in your Poltergeist configuration (see documentation for details).

       TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'Object.assign({}, merged, opt)')
       TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'Object.assign({}, merged, opt)')
```

*I've read a lot of threads, and some of them were about phantomjs not being able to work with ES6 but the newer version 2.1.1 should be alright with that.*

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Version 2.1.1 of PhantomJS is roughly equivalent to a 7 year old version of Safari.  It does not support ES6 and you will need to transpile and polyfill all JS code to be ES5 compatible in order to use it.  There was a PhantomJS 2.5 beta which brought it a bit closer to modern browser support, but that has been abandoned in favor of just recommending to use headless chrome if you want/need headless testing with ES6 support.

Comment: Okay. So i shouldn't use PhantomJS but instead something like ChromeDriver and Capybara-Selenium?

Comment: @PeterAndersen If you don't need to support old browsers with your project, are writing ES6 JS, and aren't transpiling/polyfilling - yes.

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much! Would you recommend it?

Comment: @PeterAndersen Too soon to be shipping straight ES6 code?  That's completely dependent on the target market for your project.  The one downside to selenium w/ chrome is that currently it's slower than Poltergeist/PhantomJS is (but it supports more).

Comment: Young tech people - i will go with it :)!

Comment: You should just need to specify your Capybara driver as `:selenium_chrome_headless`  (and install selenium-webdriver gem and chromedriver)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement Selenium but it required my Mac to run Xcode.

I have El Capitan, so i installed an old version through Apples support forum but it didn't work. (And it's taking up to 12.7 GB!)
I tried looking for an answer again with PhantomJS and found an [answer here](https://github.com/babel/babel-brunch/issues/59) where they talk about Babel.

So i added:

`import "babel-polyfill";`

to the top op my js-file the test succeeded and now i can continue my work!

Comment: Selenium should not require XCode, are you sure you weren’t trying to install `capybara-WebKit` rather than selenium?